# Resolve spark-avro error = Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.avro

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark, avro

I am trying to use the [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) library to process avro files. I am using SBT:

build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.0",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "1.0.0")
```

tester.scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import com.databricks.spark.avro._

object tester {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SimpleApplication").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    // Creates a DataFrame from a specified file
    val df = sqlContext.load("episodes.avro", "com.databricks.spark.avro")
  }
}
```

when I run tester in IntelliJ IDE, I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:        org/apache/avro/mapred/FsInput
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation.newReader(AvroRelation.scala:111)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.AvroRelation.<init>(AvroRelation.scala:53)
    at com.databricks.spark.avro.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:290)
```

when I run:

```
$ sbt package
$ ~/spark-1.3.1/bin/spark-submit --class "tester" target/scala-2.10/project_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.avro
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.lookupDataSource(ddl.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ddl.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:697)
```

What can I do to resolve this error? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"sbt package" will not include your dependencies, try [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the build.sbt file to:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.0",
  "com.databricks" %% "spark-avro" % "1.0.0",
  "org.apache.avro" % "avro" % "1.7.7",
  "org.apache.avro" % "avro-mapred" % "1.7.7")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("org", "slf4j", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "spark", xs @_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", "minlog", xs @_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("javax", "activation", xs @_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("javax", "xml", "stream", xs @_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("org", "apache", "commons", xs @_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case PathList("com", "google", "common", xs @_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case "org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factories/package-info.class" => MergeStrategy.first
  case "org/apache/hadoop/yarn/factory/providers/package-info.class" => MergeStrategy.first
  case "org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/package-info.class" => MergeStrategy.first
  case x if x.startsWith("META-INF") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x if x.startsWith("plugin.properties") => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => {
    val oldStrategy = (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value
    oldStrategy(x)
  }
}
```

and used the command

```
$ sbt assembly
```

to build the jar. Everything works now.